# Keras gives ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a question. I'm trying to determine if the cancer is benign or malignant. But the dataset gives the output information as a number. 2 is a benign tumor, 4 is a malignant tumor .I want it to be in the form of string. And when I try to write the output information to the string, it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'malignant tumor'
```

The code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Activation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/A/Desktop/Python/Data/breast-cancer-wisconsin1.data")
df.drop(["1000025"], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.replace("?", round(df.mean().mean()), inplace=True)
a = df["2.1"]
a[a==2] = "benign tumor"
a[a==4] = "malignant tumor"
inp = np.array(df[["5","1","1.1","1.2","2","1.3","3","1.4","1.5"]])
outp = np.array(df["2.1"])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_dim = 9))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
model.fit(inp, outp, epochs = 5, batch_size = 32, validation_split = 0.13)
```

Original Dataset:

```
     1000025  5   1  1.1  1.2  2 1.3   3  1.4  1.5  2.1

0    1002945  5   4    4    5  7  10   3    2    1    2
1    1015425  3   1    1    1  2   2   3    1    1    2
2    1016277  6   8    8    1  3   4   3    7    1    2
3    1017023  4   1    1    3  2   1   3    1    1    2
4    1017122  8  10   10    8  7  10   9    7    1    4
..       ... ..  ..  ...  ... ..  ..  ..  ...  ...  ...
693   776715  3   1    1    1  3   2   1    1    1    2
694   841769  2   1    1    1  2   1   1    1    1    2
695   888820  5  10   10    3  7   3   8   10    2    4
696   897471  4   8    6    4  3   4  10    6    1    4
697   897471  4   8    8    5  4   5  10    4    1    4
```

Changed Dataset:

```
     5   1  1.1  1.2  2 1.3   3  1.4  1.5              2.1

0    5   4    4    5  7  10   3    2    1     benign tumor
1    3   1    1    1  2   2   3    1    1     benign tumor
2    6   8    8    1  3   4   3    7    1     benign tumor
3    4   1    1    3  2   1   3    1    1     benign tumor
4    8  10   10    8  7  10   9    7    1  malignant tumor
..  ..  ..  ...  ... ..  ..  ..  ...  ...              ...
693  3   1    1    1  3   2   1    1    1     benign tumor
694  2   1    1    1  2   1   1    1    1     benign tumor
695  5  10   10    3  7   3   8   10    2  malignant tumor
696  4   8    6    4  3   4  10    6    1  malignant tumor
697  4   8    8    5  4   5  10    4    1  malignant tumor
```

What is wrong? Must output be integer?

Comment: In machine learning, loss values calculates according to numerical labels. Keras can not initalize your string labels to common format(float). You can handle this situation with basic if-else structure if you prefer!

Comment: My thanks!! ıf you vote up my comment other people can see also!! good luck in your work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In machine learning, loss values calculates according to numerical labels. Keras can not initalize your string labels to common format(float). You can handle this situation with basic if-else structure if you prefer!